# Missing References: .net core Visual Studio 2017 - SSIS Integration

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, ssis, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

A consultant modified our project (asp.net core C#), in VS15, to add a call to a SSIS package.

We are getting errors compiling this code in VS17.

```
using System.Data.Sql;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices;
using static Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.PackageInfo;

var intSvc = new IntegrationServices(new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(Database.GetDbConnection().ConnectionString));
....
....
```

Errors

```
Error CS0234 The type or namespace name 'Sql' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
Error CS0234 The type or namespace name 'Management' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.SqlServer' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'IntegrationServices' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
....
....
```

Is Visual Studio 2017 simply incapable of supporting SSIS calls? Or do I simply need to find these libraries and create explicit references to them?

Comment: FYI: A decision was made to invoke the SSIS package from a stored procedure, which negated the need for these troublesome dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems there is no support for SSIS in VS 2017 until VS 2017 update 3 (15.3)  according to [this link](http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/MVC/Post/Thread/17912b4a-4643-4a4e-86ef-18cd05da5b2e?category=sqlintegrationservices)(June 2017).

> Support for Integration Services for Visual Studio 2017 is in
>   progress, but is not yet available on launch day. For now we recommend
>   using SSDT for VS2015 if you need to use all of the BI project types
>   together in a solution, but stay tuned to [this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssdt/2017/03/10/sql-server-data-tools-17-0-rc-and-ssdt-in-vs2017/#) for updates
>   on this.

According to [this discussion](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/51221/vs2017-ssdt-no-project-templates-for-ssis.html) there will be SSIS support in VS 2017 update 3 (15.3), which was released yesterday (15.08.2017). It will be shipped like separate `.exe` installer. Here is quote from this discussion:

> SSIS heavily rely on COM, and we have dependencies on VSTA, old SSIS runtime (to support multiple target server version), so we need an exe installer (like SSDT for VS2015 installer) to bundle everything. Our installer can be found in SSDT download page soon. I will let all of you know once it is released. Currently we are targeting this week or early next week, as long as everything goes well.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to re-add references to those asemblies? Right-click on the Reference inside your project, click Add Reference and re-add all those assembies that are missing.